# Encounter "Must use import to load ES Module" while using vue3-recaptcha2 in Quasar Framework SSR

Tags: recaptcha, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I am getting

> Must use import to load ES Module: project/node_modules/vue3-recaptcha2/index.js require() of ES modules is not supported. require() of project/node_modules/vue3-recaptcha2/index.js from /project folder is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules. Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /project/node_modules/vue3-recaptcha2/package.json.

I migrated to quasar v2 and

Got the error above when i entry quasar dev -m ssr in quasar framework v2
It works on non ssr mode though.

Update:
I upgrade to nodejs 16.11.1 and the error now becomes this

> require() of ES Module /project/node_modules/vue3-recaptcha2/index.js from /project not supported. Instead change the require of index.js in /project to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.